# Sitecore and public website FormAuthontication issue

Tags: asp.net, authentication, sitecore, sitecore6

When open the sitecore portal and public website in same browser different tab I'm getting a "Application access denied." error (Below image). 
I found how it happens. First I log into sitecore portal and then I log into public website where both open at same browser. Then I click on sitecore tree item, it redirects to sitecore portal home page. `(http://myWebsite/sitecore/shell/default.aspx)`

In public website I used FormAuthontication cookie and server session to handle each user. But I figure out that sitecore also use that FormAuthontication cookie.

When I log into sitecore it will create FormAuthontication cookie. But I log into public website that FormAuthontication cookie get modified.

So, there is a conflict between this FormAuthontication cookie and sitecore redirect to sitecore home page.
Is there's a way to handle this situation?

[image: Error page]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to have 2 different sessions that will use both `FormAuthentication` to the same domain in the same browser. This cannot work.

The simplest solution here would be to add another binding to your application, e.g. `sitecore.myWebsite` and

- login to **Sitecore** back end using this binding (`http://sitecore.myWebsite/sitecore/shell/default.aspx`)
- for the standard access to the site just use the `http://myWebsite` url.

If you're testing this locally, remember to add entry to your **hosts** file:

```
127.0.0.1 sitecore.myWebsite
```